# C, string intern pool and DLLs?

Tags: c, dll, string-pool

Many scripting languages have some form of `C` extensions.

How do they resolve the problem of reference equality when interned `strings` / `symbols` can be either allocated from the main process or from the `dll`?

Is there any form of initializing a String Pool in the main process, and then use it on the loaded `dll` as if it were already initialized without passing any pointers to an instance of it?

In my case, my String Pool is global and its header file only exposes an `initialize`, `deinitialize` and `intern` functions.

Comment: Would you mind to post a [example]?

Comment: They solve it by making the heap global as well.  Giving a DLL its own heap is not entirely impossible, but usually a nasty accident caused by linking an incompatible CRT version.  Much grief.